# iOS Objective-c: how to set and ImageView from an URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimageview

Evening, I'm trying to set an ImageView.image (an IBOutlet in this case) with an image downloaded from the web.

I've already ridden a lot of questions about this in stack overflow.

And I've found this common answer:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png"];

 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

 NSLog(@"imageData: %@", data);

 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

 NSLog(@"image: %@", image);

 self.imageView.image = image;
```

But of course in my case does not work. My logs are always null.

Can you please tell me which is the problem?

Comment: what the result you get here `url`

Comment: "http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png". The right one.

Comment: Did you any log regarding Transport security exception

Comment: your problem solved or still there

Comment: The problem Was about Transport Security

Comment: accept the correct answer if it worked for you

Comment: I will, I still have to wait the 5 minutes :) people here are faster than flash gordon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to run it on iOS 8 +

Please add this to your info.plist

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
   </dict>
```

And everything should be fine :)

**WHY ??**

iOS 8 onwards http is not allowed you have to use either https or add exception to your info.plist :)

Comment: That was the problem! :)

Comment: @the-miotz : Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

This URL is HTTP type so you need to set NSAppTransportSecurity at your plist file.

For that process is

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

[image]

This might help you. Please let me know if having any problem regarding this.

Comment: why you posted the same answer again

Answer (score 1):

you should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library. It can cache image from url also. and use very simple

```
[yourImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"image-url"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"]]
```

place holder image is showed in case the image hasn't load yet.